# How can I access a property of an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, spotify

So this is probably a dumb question, but I am new to JavaScript and didn't manage to find an answer anywhere else.

I am trying to get the title and artist from a spotify url. I do this by using 2 api's: Isomorphic Unfetch and spotify-url-info.

This is my code:

```
getPreview(url).then(data => console.log(data))
```

and when i run that code it displays this:

```
{
  date: '1961-10-20T00:00:00.000Z',   
  title: "Can't Help Falling in Love",
  type: 'track',
  track: "Can't Help Falling in Love",
  description: undefined,
  artist: 'Elvis Presley',
  image: 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273f96cefb0197694ad440c3314',
  audio: 'https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/5b97db904e564c1b7d140ef45cb83b1da4233d17',
  link: 'https://open.spotify.com/track/44AyOl4qVkzS48vBsbNXaC',
  embed: 'https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:44AyOl4qVkzS48vBsbNXaC'
}
```

But now my question is, how do I extract the title and artist to  a seperate variable so I could use the data?

Comment: [You can use the data _without_ doing that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#objects_and_properties).

Comment: I think your question is mainly about the fact that the result is asynchronous? You could declare the function/method calling `getPreview` as async and then use await and manipulate the rest in a synchronous way.
`async function test() {const data = await getPreview(url);const title = data.title; /* do other things in a synchronous way  */}`

Comment: I'm almost positive that @user3252327 is right about what the actual is.  The OP should add an edit showing how exactly they are trying to access the data and what error they are getting as part of an [mcve].  Until then we are just guessing.

Comment: @isherwood Why did you reopen this?  The comments on the answer below show that this is another duplicate of how to access values outside of a promise chain.  The OP still hasn't edited their question to show how they are actually trying to access data.

Comment: The two comments above raised doubt. I'd rather give the benefit of that doubt since I had unilaterally closed it.

Answer (score 2):

you could do

```
const {title, artist} = data
```

that would get you two different variables. one containing the artist and the other one containing the title, as long as their keys match the `data` object;

or you could do

```
const music = {title: data.title, artist: data.artist}
```

that will create a new object with the title, and track.
like so:

```
{
  title: "can't help falling in love",
  artist: "Elvis Presley"
}
```

but you can absolutely use their data without destructuring, like I did before, you can use `data.artist` and so on. for example:

```
console.log(data.artist) //"Elvis Presley"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please show me how exactly I should apply this. Because I am kinda confused where I should put this. If i try replacing the console.log(data) with const music = {title: data.title, artist: data.artist} it would give me an error.

Comment: what error? could you be more specific?

Comment: If I have `getPreview(url).then({const: music = {title: data.title, artist: data.artist}})
            
            console.log(music)` as an example it would show this:

`ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.execute (E:\DiscordMusicBot\commands\play.js:97:58)     
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (E:\DiscordMusicBot\index.js:62:9)  
`

Comment: you should do:

`getPreview(url).then(data => {
  const music = {title: data.title, artist: data.artist}
  console.log(music)
});`

Comment: How can I access the title and artist from outside getPreview() constructor? Because I need those to put them in another constructor and if I try to just do something like `music.title` it says that music is not defined.

Comment: That seems to work but if i try to access it it returns undefined

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise